# Running 3 for loops in parallel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have three mobile operators O1,O2, and O3, each of them has its own mobile ( N_M_O1,N_M_O2, and N_M_O3) they are sharing the base stations (B1 and B2) represented by (conter_B1,conter_B2) I need to associate every mobile that belongs to (operator (O1) or operator (O2) or operator (O3)) to the base stations (B1 and B2)independently,however each mobile should ask the base stations (B1,B2) first if the conter_B1 and conter_B2 more than 10 they reject to associate with the next mobile (which is number 11). 
The problem is the implementation of multiple loops in Matlab will be sequencially means that Matlab will run loop1 then finish all iterations (for example if have 200 iterations) then start to run the second loop (loop2) and update the result after that start to run the third loop3
I need to run all the loops (loop1,loop2,loop3) at the same time and update the result at the same time keeping in mind the result will update the same conter for all (conter_B1 and conter_B2):
The code below follows the normal way of Matlab not parallel only for giving an example of multiple loops

```
 N_M_O1=10;
 N_M_O2=12;
 N_M_O3=13;
 conter_B1=0;
 conter_B2=0;
 x=[2 3 5 8 6 3 4 5 8 9];
 y=[2 3 6 5 2 9 4 6 3 5];
 x2=[2 8 5 8 6 3 6 5 6 9 10 12];
 y2=[9 3 6 9 7 9 4 6 8 5 1 23];
 x3=[2 3 1 8 6 3 55 5 6 9 2 3 5];
 y3=[2 4 6 4 6 5 4 6 6 4 12 32 3];
 for m=1:N_M_O1
   z(m)=x(m)+y(m);
     if z(m)>10
         conter_B1=conter_B1+1;
     else 
         conter_B2=conter_B2+1;
     end 
   end 
   for m=1:N_M_O2
   z2(m)=x2(m)+y2(m);
     if z2(m)>10
         conter_B1=conter_B1+1;
     else 
         conter_B2=conter_B2+1;
     end 
   end 
  for m=1:N_M_O3
   z3(m)=x3(m)+y3(m);
     if z3(m)>10
         conter_B1=conter_B1+1;
     else 
         conter_B2=conter_B2+1;
     end 
  end
```

Comment: *Do not use a parfor-loop when an iteration in your loop depends on the results of other iterations.* https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: That's why confuse when I used (parfor-loop) I have another condition in each loop when the conter_B1 or conter_B2 >10 do not assign the mobile to that B1 Or B2, specifically if the first loop implemented, the conter_B1 Or conter_B2 will exceed  10 only from the first loop and when the mobiles of the operator (O2) comes from the second loop they can not associate with B1,B2, because they are >10 and in this case not fair for the O2 and O3

Comment: The algorithm your code runs seems to be sequential in nature as you have pointed out. The first loop *must* run and update results before other loops can run. I suggest you think about the problem and come up with an algorithm that does have *the potential* to be parallelized before trying to use parfor or anything else.

Comment: Thank you, dear JROOK, The potential of the loops to be parallelized, this what I am looking for if you can help me to do that without parfor-loop

Comment: But the code you have given does NOT show that! The first loop has to do its job and finish before the other two can even start or the results will be wrong! The order strictly is `LOOP1 => LOOP2 => LOOP3`. Suppose you had a magic wand that could run this in parallel. Please edit the question to describe what should happen.

Comment: Specially, what should happen to conter_B1 and conter_B2 in a parallel execution?How should the program resolve concurrent updates to those variables? Answering these questions is the first step to any parallelization effort.

Comment: Thank you very much Dear JrooK , this is a really good point. for example if the three loops match the condition and need to increment conter_B1 how can the result update, is there any conflect will be during the implementation of the three loops

Comment: Please also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you only want:

```
zz = [x+y,x2+y2,x3+y3];
counter_B1 = sum(zz>10)
counter_B2 = sum(zz<=10)
```

Which will produce the same result as your 3 for loops.

Comment: Thank you dear obchardon, AS I have three loops i need to run the three loops in parallel and update the results of the three loops in parallel, specifically the result of the three loops is require to increment the same counter simulataneously (conter_B1 and conter_B2)

Comment: But... why ? This is not how parallel computing works, you can not run nested parfor loop ! And if you have several parfor loop it will be run sequentially ! What you are asking for is simply impossible. If you really want to use a parfor you have to parallelize all the operation in one unique parfor loop. Read [this article](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html) to understand how to create a valid parfor loop. But in your case I don't understand how it would be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much dear obchardon I highly appreciate your effort I will read the article to understand the situation exactly (parallel computation)